# Check if several files exists in a directory

Tags: c#

I am saving a new image everytime the uploader cropped the image and I want to check every new image if it exists. I have this code:

```
private void pictureBox5_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Selecting = false;

            // Copy the selected area.
            SelectedArea = GetSelectedArea(pictureBox5.Image, Color.Transparent, Points);

            SelectedArea.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gallery\image1cropped.png", ImageFormat.Png);


        }
```

I want it to save like image2cropped, image3cropped.. and check if it exists like

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gallery\image1cropped.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I want it to check like image2cropped, image3cropped.. and so on. 
ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand : your are saving an area to a file. The first time, you save it to image1cropped.png, and then you want automaticaly use image2cropped in order to not overwrite the first file, right ?
In this case, you can use this code :

```
        int i = 0; // set 0 to start at 1 for "image1cropped"
        string freeFileName; // the final fileName that doesn't exist

        // loop while file imageXcropped exists
        do
        {
            i++;
            freeFileName = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gallery\image" + i + "cropped.png";
        } while (File.Exists(freeFileName));

        // at this point freeFileName doesn't exists, you can use it
        // use : SelectedArea.Save(freeFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: yeah the save thing i solved it. but i want to check if they exists is it the same algorithm?

Comment: never mind i solved it.
here is my final code:

SelectedArea.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gallery\image" + NumberOfClick.ToString() + "cropped.png", ImageFormat.Png);

            string filename = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gallery\image" + NumberOfClick.ToString() + "cropped.png";

            if(File.Exists(filename))
            {
                button1.Visible = true;
                pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            }

Comment: do you want to check it before saving to not overide it or after the save to check it the file is well saved ?

Comment: so you are checking if the file exists after to save it... i'm not sure it's necessary because I think the .save methode will throw an exception if the file could not to be saved !
And with your algo, when the application is restarted, youNumberOfClick will be reseted and then image1cropped will be overwrited. Is it what you want ?
Note that in your case ".toString()" are optional ;)